# how to put a seperate view inside a splitview in template 10?

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

basically I want this splitview from MainPageView to load the departmentView which contains its own ViewModel that has an Observablecollection

> ```
>         <SplitView.Pane>
>             <Frame>
>                 <local:DepartmentsView/>
>             </Frame>
>         </SplitView.Pane>
> ```

but it has to be in sync with the navigation service. because I am relying on the template10's OnNavigatedToAsync to load my data

Comment: Your question is not clear and requires explanation

Comment: As was mentioned, you could explain some more. It seems you are putting content in the Pane where threre should be navigation. Then put the content in the SplitView.Content area as in this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-split-view-control/
Or do you need to know more about the navigation service? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. Nobody has ever asked for this before. I am not 100% sure you want the Template 10 hamburger menu in this circumstance. Why? Because the T10 HamMenu is really built around the idea of managed buttons in the Pane. There is NOTHING stopping you from simply adding your own SplitView control to your app and doing what you are wanting. The more I think about it the more I think that might be the best thing for you to do. If you think otherwise, please explain. Otherwise, just adding a SPlitView might not have been an option you thought of until now. The HamMenu in T10 uses the SplitView control.

Comment: I'm using the same approach in some of my views. Basically I added a nested splitview in the main SplitView's content. This way I can overlay a different frame to show contextual information about the selected item in the main view. -Without- affecting the navigation path of the main view. Sort of like a modaldialog/contentdialog.